# Maven phantom managed dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I just got into a very weird dependency issue, never saw that before.

I have a parent project which declares in dependencyManagement the version for the Netty libary:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-bom</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.29.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have submodules that declare dependencies on Netty JARs, for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For some reason, the retained Netty version is 4.1.27.Final **AND IT IS NOT MENTIONED ANYWHERE**!!

I thought Eclipse may be causing the issue, so I tried with the mvn executable on command line - same thing. I thought that may be some conflict with installed POMs/JARs in my local Maven repository, so I removed the entire directory inside the higher com directory - same thing.

I have no idea what is going here - never saw such behavior from Maven.

Using Eclipse, if I look at the effective POM for my parent project, I see all the Netty dependencies with version **4.1.27.Final** inside `dependencyManagement`. But I have no idea where it gets these dependencies from...

---

The parent POM (only dependencies and dependencyManagement):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-bom</artifactId>
            <version>Apple-SR1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.401</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.29.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dnsjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>dnsjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>26.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectjrt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The child POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- dependency to other child modules -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>dnsjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>dnsjava</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.kenglxn.qrgen</groupId>
        <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Maybe [Enforcer plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) can spot anything suspicious?

Comment: @yegodm I tried it - no error so no dependency convergence issues.

Comment: Please attach both pom.xml files to the question (excerpts only: `dependencies` and `dependencyManagement` sections from both pom.xml files).

Comment: @krokodilko I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from `spring-boot-dependencies` which declares `netty-bom` too.
Perhaps changing the order helps. You may also exclude it.